# How to add a div element to a php function

Tags: php, html

I have working php code which I have added to my wordpress themes functions.php file.

Everything is working great. All I am trying to do is add a div class to be able to style the output.

I am not sure how to do that, any advice is greatly appreciated. I tried adding

```
<div class="custom"> echo get_option      ('woo_customtext'</div>);
```

However the site returns a page error. The full code I added was as follows:

```
add_action( 'woo_post_inside_before',     'woo_add_custom' ); 

function woo_add_custom() { 

if (is_single()){ 
echo get_option ('woo_customtext'); 
} 
}
```

Comment: `<div class="custom"> echo get_option      ('woo_customtext'</div>);` is pretty far from valid syntax.

Comment: Posting the error could be useful. 

You are also not echoing properly it seems. Where are the <?php ?> tags?

Comment: This is kind of a mess. Is this being done in Wordpress?

Comment: Yes, I actually got the advice from woo themes! M Miller helped me out with the solution I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if (is_single()) {
    echo '<div class="custom">'.get_option('woo_customtext').'</div>';
}
```

Or

```
if (is_single()) {
    ?>
<div class="single"><?php echo get_option('woo_customtext'); ?></div>
    <?php
}
```

To mix HTML in with PHP, you need to either print it as a string (hence the `'` quotes in the first example) or exit PHP before writing HTML (hence the `?>` and `<?php` in the second).

Comment: Miller, thank you for your support and advice.  echo '<div class="custom">'.get_option('woo_customtext').'</div>'; worked perfectly. I can see what you mean now regarding printing it as a string. Thank you again !